# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'importlater'

Tags: python

I was trying to use cjklib under Python 2.7.6, and I got the following error message.
cjklib was installed using 'pip install cjklib'.

Error message is as follows:

```
Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.0 (64-bit)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:15) [MSC v.1
500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from cjklib import characterlookup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cjklib\characterlookup.py", line 24, in <m
odule>
    from sqlalchemy import select, union
  File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 13, in <modu
le>
    from sqlalchemy.sql import (
  File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\__init__.py", line 7, in <m
odule>
    from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import (
  File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\expression.py", line 37, in
 <module>
    functions = util.importlater("sqlalchemy.sql", "functions")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'importlater'
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cjklib` is an old module from may 2012, and meanwhile `util.importlater` was replaced by `util.dependency`. Unfortunately, you have few options:

- Report the bug to the `cjklib` team, hoping there will be someone willing to update the library,
- Fix the `cjklib` yourself (and contribute back to the project, fork on github),
- Find another up-to-date library that does the same thing as `cjklib`,
- Downgrade SQLAlchemy and related dependencies to under 0.7 (this can make other python modules inoperative).

Comment: I am pretty naive to python and cjklib, but it looks like upgrading SQLAlchemy solves the problem.